# Child Related List at Parent Level

Tags: related-list, docusign

Does anyone know of a way to display a Child's related list at the Parent record level?  I have a custom object with a Master-Detail relationship to the Opportunity object.  We utilize DocuSign and have created the DocuSign envelop button on the child object.  As a result, the Docusign status related list is not available at the Opportunity level.  Is there any way of getting it there?  Thanks

Comment: You will need to use `VisualForce`.

Comment: you should be able to place a VisualForce page as a component within the standard Opportunity detail page. Because the Opportunity has multiple children, each with multiple Docusign children, you would show, in effect, a tree view (styling it is another matter). See http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/05/08/inline-visualforce-pages-with-standard-page-layouts/ as a general guide

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly add a grandchild object as a related list on an object - there has to be a direct relationship. You can certainly pursue the Visualforce route if you wish.

Alternatively, you could add a new custom lookup from the Docusign status object to Opportunity, and then use Process Builder or a trigger to populate that lookup with the parent Opportunity's ID. This would create a direct relationship which would allow you to include the related list as usual.

Comment: This seems to be a question of how to display records where the relationship already exist. If my understanding is correct, your answer does not really address the OP.